# Is replacing with the Tech Slang needed?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm having a doubt that, recently I found this question in Askubuntu :[How do I watch Youtube videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400550/how-do-i-watch-youtube-videos)
On seeing that my instinct told me to edit the question as : **Flash player not working in firefox**
But on the second thought I knew that how will the people with poor tech interaction will find such a question with tech specifications in the site. So what is recommended? Let it remain as is?

P.S: I didn't meant this question only

Comment: **Never** edit a question's title *away* from an actual question. The title is supposed to be a *question*. "Flash player not working in firefox" is *not* a question.

Comment: Then, "How to repair the flash player?"

Answer (score 8):

**No**

"How do I " questions are encouraged for search optimization since it's what people that are trying to find an answer will use.

A user will search for "how do i get youtube working"

Tech terms are tags.

A technical person will browse the firefox and flash tags.

Opinion from experience, but someone may disagree.

Comment: i don't understand what you meant

Comment: See if the edit clarifies it.

Comment: I meant what if I edit the question to 'flash not working in firefox'

Comment: No.  A user won't search for that set of words.

Comment: @hbdgaf i think http://askubuntu.com/questions/400550/how-do-i-watch-youtube-videos it is an off-topic ques.

Comment: It's not.  It just doesn't say on Ubuntu.  It's implied though.